# ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number with name “” too small Sonar qube

Tags: azure, azure-devops, sonarqube, devops

i am getting error while publishing results on sonar.

> Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.result.ResultMapException: Error attempting to get column 'RAWLINEHASHES' from result set.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number 2 with name "_SYSSMU2_111974964$" too small
>
> Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.result.ResultMapException: Error attempting to get column 'RAWLINEHASHES' from result set.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number 2 with name "_SYSSMU2_111974964$" too small

Pipeline executed for 2 hr 30 mins.

Can you please help ?

Comment: Can you give more context information? Which database are you using? What shall your pipeline do?

Comment: Hello Elmar Brauch, I am executing a pipeline that executes testCases. And in order to execute these test cases it gets connected with SQL. There are 75-6 task in pipeline. Of which executing testCase task is completed successfully and while publishing to sonar cube failure occurs.

Comment: PS:- Pipeline executed for 2:30 hr.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting is ORA-01555. Which is an Oracle error message.

Your pipeline is executing something against an Oracle database, which after it has run for a long time, gives the error.

For ways to avoid this error see: https://blog.enmotech.com/2018/09/10/ora-01555-snapshot-old-error-ways-to-avoid-ora-01555-snapshot-too-old-error/

Comment: Hello shairaj Bhaiji, pipeline i am executing does not interact with Oracle database. It does interact with sql databse. Task of executing tescases is completed successfully.  Just that while publishing results to sonar i am getting this error.

Comment: It looks like your Sonar installation use Oracle.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use pessimistic read, this will let other transactions read the data while, your query is reading, but will prevent them from modifying the data, so your main query's snapshot will stay consistent.